# WeasyPrint report generation with SVG image in base64 format with CJK characters

Tags: encoding, utf-8, cairo, cjk, weasyprint

I'm using [WeasyPrint](https://weasyprint.org/) to create reports. I've been facing difficulties adding SVGs to the report.

- I tried adding inline SVG and it doesn't work as explained [here](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/75)
- Now I'm trying to add SVGs using base64 (as suggested [here](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/75#issuecomment-267452666)) and everything looks fine until I use CJK characters.

Attaching part of the html that I'm feeding WeasyPrint with ([JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pinkynrg/rysq368v/)).

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <img class='chart_image'
      src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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' />
  </body>
</html>
```

After processing the above code, WeasyPrint output looks like the following attached image:

[image]

I'm trying to understand if it is something I can fix by, maybe, explicitly setting the encoding somewhere where it is missing or if it something WeasyPrint needs to fix internally.

Any idea how to further troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Reduce your problem to an **actual** minimalistic example. Then consider explicitly defining `encoding="utf-8"` to the XML. Then consider using XML entities for 1-2 CJK characters to see if that's a workaround.